# AWS application consistent snapshots of EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup

I'm currently setting up a small Lambda to take snapshots of all the important volumes of our EC2 instances. To guarantee application consistency I need to trigger actions inside the instances: One to quiesce the application before the snapshot and one to wake it up again after the snapshot is done. So far I have no clue how to do this.

I've thought about using SNS or SQS to notify the instances about start and stop of the snapshot, but that has several problems:

- I'll need to install (and develop) a custom listener inside the instances.
- I'll not get feedback if the quiescing/wake-up is done.

So here's my question: How can I trigger an action inside an instance from an Lambda?

But maybe I'm approaching this from the wrong direction. Is there really no simple backup solution? I know azure has a snapshot based backup service that can do application consitent backups. Did I just miss an equivalent AWS service?

---

Edit 1:

Ok, it looks like the feature 'Run Command' of AWS Systems Manager is what I really need. It allows me to run scripts, Ansible playbooks and more inside an EC2 instance. When I've got a working solution I'll post the necessary steps.

Comment: Windows or Linux systems?

Comment: Linux, but I'm interested in a windows solution too. You never know when it might come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger a Lambda function on demand:

[Using AWS Lambda with Amazon API Gateway (On-Demand Over HTTPS)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https.html)

> You can invoke AWS Lambda functions over HTTPS. You can do this by
>   defining a custom REST API and endpoint using Amazon API Gateway, and
>   then mapping individual methods, such as GET and PUT, to specific
>   Lambda functions. Alternatively, you could add a special method named
>   ANY to map all supported methods (GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE) to your
>   Lambda function. When you send an HTTPS request to the API endpoint,
>   the Amazon API Gateway service invokes the corresponding Lambda
>   function. For more information about the ANY method, see Step 3:
>   Create a Simple Microservice using Lambda and API Gateway.

Comment: Neat. So instead of cloudwatch triggering the backups, I'll have a cronjob that runs the quiescing script and then calls the API via curl to start the snapshot. Still: Triggering the quiescing by the snapshot would be immensly useful.